# can we use join inside join in mysql?

Tags: mysql

i have 3 tables structure is below

#### tbl_login

```
login_id | login_name 
   1     |  keshav
```

#### tbl_role

```
role_id | login_id( refer to tbl_login.login_id)
 1      |    1
```

#### tbl_stuff

```
stuff_id | role_id( refer to tbl_role.role_id)
   1     |   1
```

i need data in follow format

```
stuff_id | login_name
   1     |   keshav
```

how to use JOIN to retrive the above data in mysql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep joining tables with eachother on (almost) whatever parameters you like. As far as the database engine is concerned, it doesn't care about the name or meaning of the parameters you are joining (you could be joining a name with a height for instance).

It might be helpfull to read up on joins [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

```
SELECT  st.stuff_id
        , l.login_name
FROM    dbo.tbl_stuff st
        INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_role r ON r.role_id = st.role_id
        INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_login l ON l.login_id = r.login_id
```

Comment: can we use `JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`? is there any difference?

Comment: `INNER` is implicitly used when no other join predicate is present. Personally, I always write the predicate for clarity.